# Error when displaying a page -MVC beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why do i get this error

```
The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'MyController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type MyProj.Controllers.MyController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(MyProj.Models.MyModel) on type MyProj.Controllers.MyController
```

COntroller Class :

```
public class MyController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: //
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();

        }


        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {
            string x = "Hello "+ model.name;

            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both GET actions.

Add this before your second method:

```
[HttpPost]
```

Like so:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: //
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        string x = "Hello "+ model.name;

        return View();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overload you need to add attribute to change your method name:

```
[ActionName("OverloadedName")]
```